# Searching a way to implement "human" sorting in django

Tags: python, django, sorting

I am working on a project with django-restframework where users will name objects and app is saving them in database as string (Django's varchar). Formatting of name is not defined. Examples of possible values are "1", "1A" "2B" "2-2", "Box #1" ...

I would like to order those in "human" sorting. Some developers are calling this type of sorting as "alphanumeric sort", others "human sorting".

I have tried with:

```
queryset = KlassModel.objects.all().extra(select={'intname': 'CAST(name AS INTEGER)'}).order_by('intname')
```

the output was:

```
[u'burgerland', u'Box #1', u'Box #2', u'B12', u'MyBox #22', u'OthersBox 13', u'OthersBox 14', u'MyBeatBox', u'MetaStruct', u'A', u'B', u'1A', u'1B', u'1Z', u'2G', u'2-2', u'2A', u'2A #1', u'2A1', u'11', u'11S', u'22', u'22F']
```

Which is not what I wanted. "MyBeatBox", "MetaStruct" and other words are not in alphabet order.

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: please check if this helps: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort

Comment: If you want to order by *natural sorting* a queryset you should do it on the database side. Using *natsort* on python side would be inefficient for big queries.

I think that a simple `CAST(name AS INTEGER)` is insufficient also.

Comment: Tried CAST, wrong sorting if string is made of only alphabet letters.